# How to give Schema Level permission in Azure Data Warehouse (Synapse)?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, database-schema, azure-synapse

In our Azure SQL Data Warehouse (Synapse), we have two schemas `dbo` and `staging`.
I want to give schema level permission to my *Azure Active Directory Group* users only to 'dbo' schema. The expected behaviour I'm looking for is that after giving this permission, the *Azure Active Directory Group* users shouldn't see `staging` schema when opening the database in ssms. I tried the following to create the user and give permissions but still, users see `staging` schema in their ssms.

1. I created the user and added `db_datareader` role using the following:

```
CREATE USER [Azure Active Directory Group] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'Azure Active Directory Group'
```

2. And then grant schema level permission using:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [Azure Active Directory Group]
```

3. The following query returns:

```
select pr.name,
       pr.type_desc,
       pe.permission_name,
       pe.state_desc,
       pe.class_desc,
       object_name(pe.major_id)

FROM sys.database_principals AS pr
JOIN sys.database_permissions AS pe
    ON pe.grantee_principal_id = pr.principal_id where name='Azure Active Directory Group Users';
```

[image]

Does anybody know how I can give schema level permission? I'm stuck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[db_datareader](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15): Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can read all data from all user tables. It means the `db_datareader` role can view all the schemas. So we need to revoke this permission.

There are two ways to reslove the problem:

1. Revoke the `db_datareader` permission and grant the permission to the user.

```sql
EXEC sp_droprolemember 'db_datareader', 'Azure Active Directory Group'

GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [Azure Active Directory Group]
```

2. We also can add a custom role and grant the permission to the role.

```sql
CREATE ROLE <Role_Name>; 

GRANT SELECT ON schema::dbo TO <Role_Name>;

EXEC sp_addrolemember '<Role_Name>', 'Azure Active Directory Group'
```

Comment: thanks, @Joseog Xu, why can't I directly use `GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [Azure Active Directory Group]` after revoking `db_datareader`? why do I need to create `external_users` role?

Comment: You also can directly use `GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [Azure Active Directory Group]`.  `external_users` is the name of the custom role I created, you don’t need to create a role. The custom role is created so that this permission can be reused.